# Android - trigger adjustResize

Tags: android, react-native

I wrapped my form in a `<ScrollView>` and I set my manifest `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` (default of react native). Now when I manually focus a field with my finger touch event, and the field is covered by keyboard, it successfully scrolls to the field I just pressed.

However, if I pragmatically focus the next field (`refToTextInput.focus()`), it is not scrolling to that next field (focus does happen). I need the scroll to happen.

How can I trigger the `adjustResize` again, so it scrolls into view the next field I focused?

## Manual focus - good

Here is what happens on manual focusing the password field, screencast:

[image]

## Programmatic focus - bad - fail

However if my focus is in the "username" field and then I do `this.refToPassword.focus()` on the `onSubmitEditing` of the username field. Focus moves to the password input, and the keyboard doesnt flash (this is perfect I don't want the keyboard to flash). HOWEVER, the scroll view doesn't scroll to this field. Here is screencast of programmatic focus:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is not the exact solution that I am proposing. However, you might consider this as a workaround.

You might consider hiding the keyboard programatically and showing the keyboard again on requesting focus programatically in the next `EditText` field. So the complete pseudo code for requesting the focus in next field will be something like.

```
public void requestFocusToNextField(View view) {
    view.requestFocus(); 
    hideKeyboard();
    showKeyboard();
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Reaz for this idea. I also did this with adding a keyboard listener, and doing a `Keyboard.dismiss()`, and then once hidden, then i focus the next input and this brings up the keyboard and focus the next field. However this keyboard wait to dismiss and come back is very unprofessional looking. I uploaded screencasts to original post showing how nice it looks with no keyboard flash.